# How to fill a triangle using lines?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, rasterizing

I'm trying to fill a triangle using horizontal lines and I can't figure out what's wrong with my current method. Before anyone says to just use fillPolygon, I can't use that. I need to fill it using lines.
It seems to work ok in some situations and completely break in others.

[image]

That's how it should look. But then I tried applying my method to a rotating 3D cube and...

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong. Also, the red borders are also one of my triangle methods. Those work perfectly and the filled triangles and the outlined triangles have the same vertices inputted.

```
public void filledTri(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3){
    int[] xs = {x1,x2,x3};
    int[] ys = {y1,y2,y3};
    //Sort vertices in vertical order so A/1 is highest and C/3 is lowest
    int I,tempx,tempy;
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
        I = i-1;
        tempx = xs[i];
        tempy = ys[i];
        while(I>=0&&tempy<ys[I]){
            xs[I+1] = xs[I];
            ys[I+1] = ys[I];
            I--;
        }
        xs[I+1] = tempx;
        ys[I+1] = tempy;
    }
    //Set left and right edges
    linepts ab = new linepts(xs[0],ys[0],xs[1],ys[1]),
    ac = new linepts(xs[0],ys[0],xs[2],ys[2]);
    linepts[] lines = {ab.getEndX() < ac.getEndX() ? ab : ac,
    ab.getEndX() > ac.getEndX() ? ab : ac,
    new linepts(xs[1],ys[1],xs[2],ys[2])};
    //Fill triangle
    int startY = ys[0],endY = ys[2];
    for(int y=startY;y<=endY;y++){
        if(y>ys[1])
        horizontalLine((int)Math.round(lines[2].getX(y)),
        y,
        (int)Math.round(lines[1].getX(y)));
        else
        horizontalLine((int)Math.round(lines[0].getX(y)),
        y,
        (int)Math.round(lines[1].getX(y)));
    }
```

getX(int y) gets me the x coordinate where the line passes through the y value. If it's a horizontal line it just returns the line's start x

Point A is the highest on screen and the lowest value, B is the middle, and C is the lowest on screen and highest value

I'm using a buffered image on a jframe to draw it if that helps.

Comment: All I see in the first 'working' image is a solid white or near white fill. Are the lines that are supposed to appear there, parallel? Consider drawing them to an image then using a `TexturePaint` to fill a `Shape` (the triangle in this case).

Comment: *"I have no idea what's wrong."* Hmmm.. Now I look more closely at the images, I realise I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Where are the horizontal lines in the first triangle? **General Tip:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you show the implementations of `getX` and `horizontalLine`? Without close scrutiny the problem may lie with them.

Comment: `public double getX(int y){
        double m = ((double)(y1-y2))/((double)(x1-x2));
        if(m==0)
        return x1;
        else
        return (double)(y-y1)/m+x1;
    }`

Comment: ``public void horizontalLine(int x1,int y,int x2){
        //Only one of these will run, the second one only runs
        //if x2 < x1
        for(int x=x1;x<=x2;x++)
        pixel(x,y);
        for(int x=x1;x>=x2;x--)
        pixel(x,y);
    }``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen what you are doing in a [Software Renderer tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBUbVOok816vTl1K9vV1GgH5). It is explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRksA2KGLZ4&t=0s&index=9&list=PLEETnX-uPtBUbVOok816vTl1K9vV1GgH5) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbB5taqJsS4&list=PLEETnX-uPtBUbVOok816vTl1K9vV1GgH5&index=9) episodes.

What he does there is scanning the longest to get every pixel on that line, it stores the min X value and max X value, (given by the other 2 lines). He originally makes it for specific triangles, but then he upgrades the code to accept generic triangles.

Here's a nice diagram to explain that:
[image]

I assume what you're experiencing is because of projecting 3D triangles into 2D ones (clipping, triangles get infinite coordinates, or because you're program doesn't takes too well empty triangles.

Comment: The thing is though, the red outline triangles are given the same vertices as the filled triangles. The filled triangles sometimes work and sometimes don't and I can't find any similarities in the ones that don't. This method from what I can tell is pretty fast but I feel like when I converted it from a different coding language to java, I didn't convert it right.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to draw the lines to an image, then use that image in a `TexturePaint` to fill a `Shape` (the triangle in this case).

It might look something like this: (if you use a single image containing one red line, put it over a random BG color, and use a smoothed 1.5 pixel stroke to draw the shape itself in blue).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.*;

public class LinesFillShape {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    LinesFillShape() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage())));
    }

    private void drawPolygon(Graphics2D g, int sz, Random r) {
        int[] xpoints = {
            r.nextInt(sz), r.nextInt(sz), r.nextInt(sz)
        };
        int[] ypoints = {
            r.nextInt(sz), r.nextInt(sz), r.nextInt(sz)
        };
        Polygon p = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3);
        Color bg = new Color(r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255));
        g.setColor(bg);
        g.fill(p);

        g.setPaint(
                new TexturePaint(getTexture(),
                        new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 8, 8)));
        g.fill(p);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.draw(p);
    }

    private BufferedImage getImage() {
        int sz = 600;
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(sz, sz, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Random r = new Random();
        drawPolygon(g, sz, r);
        drawPolygon(g, sz, r);
        drawPolygon(g, sz, r);

        g.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    private BufferedImage getTexture() {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(8, 8, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        // TODO: something more interesting here.. 
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 8);
        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            LinesFillShape o = new LinesFillShape();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent for Java2D, but note how the texture adheres to the screen rather than the surface; for 3D, consider [`TriangleMesh`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20PhongMaterial) or [`PhongMaterial `](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavafx%5d%20PhongMaterial)

Answer (score 0):

I have not scrutinized your code but I can tell you that you are not always joining intersections with the relevant sides.

You can work as follows:

For a given scanline (some `Y`),

- compare the ordinates of the endpoints of the three sides in pairs (`Y0-Y1`, `Y1-Y2`, `Y2-Y0`),
- there will be zero or two sides that straddle `Y`; use the condition `(Yi > Y) != (Yi+1 > Y)` (indexes modulo 3), and no other,
- for the sides that straddle `Y`, compute the intersection point.

You will scan from `min(Y0, Y1, Y2)` to `max(Y0, Y1, Y2)` and each time join the two intersections.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a lot of strain especially on higher polygon models?

Comment: What do you call "a lot of strain". This solution is essentially yours, with a fix.

Comment: You can optimize this using a scanline approach, which amounts to decomposing the triangle in a triangle and a triangle or trapezoid; but as your main problem was with correctness, I showed you a bulletproof solution (yet  reasonably efficient)